# How can I deploy a Gatsby project to Firebase Hosting through Github Actions using development variables?

Tags: firebase, gatsby, github-actions, firebase-hosting

I want to deploy a development instance of my Gatsby app on Firebase Hosting. I am using Github Actions. How can I build the app using the development variables (`env.development`)?

This is my current Github Actions workflow code (which is using the production variables (`env.production`)):

```
name: DEV - Gatsby deploy to preview link
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - development
    paths:
      - "gatsby/**"

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: gatsby

jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}"
          projectId: hf5674525-development
          channelId: "preview"
```

I have tried to change `run: npm run build` with `run: NODE_ENV=development npm run build` but it still use the production variables and not the development variables which I want it to use. I also think I should use `gatsby build` instead of `npm build`.

I appreciate feedback on this.

Comment: `npm run build` should work just fine if the script is what you expect locally. What is happening when you say you have no luck? What is not happening that you want to?

Comment: @evelynhathaway sorry for the imprecise question. Updated it now. So with the current workflow script it builds with production variables, but what I want is to run the build with development variables. Not sure how to make that happen.